# Remove words from rows in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe, with a lot of trigrams and their frequencies.

How can I add a third column (let's called it finalWord) where only the last word of the trigram is displayed?

Here is an example of the dataframe:

```
x <- data.frame(trigrams = c("I have to", "I need to"), freq = c(10, 7))
```

The output should be:

```
x <- data.frame(trigrams = c("I have to", "I need to"), freq = c(10, 7), finalWord = c("to", "to"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
x$finalword <- sub(".*\\s+", '', x$trigrams)
x$finalword
#[1] "to" "to"
```

---

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_last(x$trigrams, regex="\\w+")
```